# Symfony2.8 : get User Object from form

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I've a cambobox  that loads username from another entity user , i want to create an object user from this username that i will select to submit my form

```
$builder->add('title', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'AuthentificationBundle\Entity\user',
              'property' => 'username',
              'expanded' => false,
              'multiple' => false,
              'label'    => 'Matricule',
              ))
```

i do this in my controller but i don't know how to get object user from username selected :

```
$postData = $request->request->get('CompanyEventsType'); //name of form
$name_value = $postData['title']; // field title
```

how to get object from this fild title ?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an object to the createForm() method. Assuming that the CompanyEvents model is set up correctly then you should be able to access the embedded user object.

Controller:

```
$companyEvents = new CompanyEvents();

$form = $this->createForm(
    'AuthenticationBUndle\Entity\CompanyEvents', 
    $companyEvents, 
    array() // any options
)
->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: i don't have FormType , all fields are generated automatically while generating CRUD in CompanyEventsType .